# Rolling Ratio in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, division, rolling-computation

I'm trying to perform a rolling ratio between each couple of subsequent rows:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0],columns=['close'])
```

The one underneath throws the following error:

```
data.close.rolling(3, win_type='triang').divide()
```

> 'Window' object has no attribute 'divide'

Expected output: 2.0/1.0, 3.0/2.0, 4.0/3.0, 5.0/4.0

Comment: Are you able to give a desired output?

Comment: pls have a look at the edit, basically it's the second divided by the first, the third divided by the second etc..

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
data.close / data.close.shift(-1)

Comment: Be careful with shifting, esp. if underlying data is indexed by datetime.